# How to secure Struts actions with Spring single-sign-on

Tags: struts2, single-sign-on, action, spring-saml

Currently I am using Struts 2 framework in my web application, now I have integrated single-sign-on with the help of Spring SAML extension and ADFS server, now every thing is working fine except Struts 2 actions,

when I am going to call/hit any Struts action like example.com/myapplication/myactionname.action URL then Spring SSO never ask for authentication.

But when I hit any .jsp OR .js OR .css OR .html file

Ex. example.com/myapplication/test.jsp  file in application it will prompt for authentication.

[image: Screenshot image]

Any ideas how to secure Struts actions with Spring single-sign-on, so that anybody can't access action URL directly without any authentication ?

Comment: When I see such window then it signals that some errors or exceptions occured, and I go to see to server logs.

Comment: Can you post your Spring Security configuration?

Comment: There is no error or exception in logs, using <security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/> we can exclude any URL pattern from Spring single sign on security, but how to include any URL pattern/Struts actions in spring security.

Comment: Please post the contents of your application-security.xml

Comment: <security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>  <security:http pattern="/saml/web/**" use-expressions="false">
<security:access-denied-handler error page="/saml/web/metadata/login"/>
<security:form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-page="/saml/web/metadata/login" default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
<security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/></security:http>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution, I have both Spring and Struts filter in my web.xml , I just changed filter order as below and its working for me.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```